# Insert a plain text inside a DIV with XSLT

Tags: jquery, css, xslt

I'm creating a dynamic Menu using XSLT. Inside one DIV, I must put a text that's not an attribute.

My XLST:

```
<xsl:template match="/MenuConfig">
        <div data-sidebar> <--- PROBLEM!!!
            <ul class="sidebar list-unstyled">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </ul>
        </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Menu | Item">
    <li class="{@class}">
        <a href="{@location}"><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></a>
        <xsl:if test="Item">
            <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Item" />
          </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML (just an example. Actually, the XML doesn't matter):

```
<MenuConfig>
<Menu name="name-1" location="location 1" title="Menu 1">
    <Item name="name-1.1" location="location 1.1.jsp" title="Menu 1.1"/>
    <Item name="name-1.2" location="location 1.2.jsp" title="Menu 1.2"/>
    <Item name="name-1.3" location="location 1.3.jsp" title="Menu 1.3">
        <Item name="name-1.3.1" location="location 1.3.1.jsp" title="Menu 1.3.1"/>
        <Item name="name-1.3.2" location="location 1.3.2.jsp" title="Menu 1.3.2"/>
    </Item>
    <Item name="name-1.4" location="location 1.4.jsp" title="Menu 1.3">
        <Item name="name-1.4.1" location="location 1.4.1.jsp" title="Menu 1.4.1"/>
        <Item name="name-1.4.2" location="location 1.4.2.jsp" title="Menu 1.4.2"/>
    </Item>
</Menu>
```

The result I need is something like this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div data-sidebar>
                <ul class="sidebar list-unstyled">
                    <li ><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="pensions/">Pensions</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="funds/">Funds</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="savings-and-investments/">Savings and Investments</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="life-insurance/">Life Insurance</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="customer-support/">Existing Customers</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="contact-u/s">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="about-us/">About Zurich Life</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to have this `data-sidebar` like this `<div data-sidebar>` because I'm using inside this js function:

```
/**
 * Mobile dropdown sidebar
 * This will generate select with options from left menu for small and xsmall devices
 * @return {void}
 */
mobileSidebar: (function(){
  var current = '';
  return function(){
    if( !$('[data-sidebar] select').length ){
      var $select = $('<select class="sidebar form-control"/>');
      $('[data-sidebar] ul li').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var active = $(this).hasClass('active') ? 'selected' : '';
ETC...
```

This JS function was made by a third part company, so it can't be changed.
When I'm running the XSLT transformation, I receive this error:

"Attribute name "data-sidebar" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character"

Is it possible to be done? There is another way to write this value inside the DIV?
I've tried to use `id="data-sidebar"` but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: your xslt is invalid. should be something like <div data-sidebar="">.

Comment: @joel-m-lamsen Hi Joel. I know it's invalid. That's my problem. I don't know how to put it. Thanks

Comment: Change the problematic code to something like the one I've suggested above and see what happens.

Comment: It worked. The result wasn't what I expected, but the JS worked and that's what matter. Thanks Joel.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen Do you mind adding this as an answer? Then, Adriano can accept it and the matter is settled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xslt is invalid. change

```
<div data-sidebar>
```

to

```
<div data-sidebar="">
```

this way, `data-sidebar` will be presented as an attribute (with an empty content). The JS will now work.